# How to label constructed lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project I need to create a game of pickup sticks, and after every turn, I need to print out a diagram of the what sticks are left and their corresponding numbers.[image: Diagram of what it should look like].  Currently what I have is

```
sticks = 20
width = 1
for x in range(1,10):
    for y in range(1,sticks):
        print('  *  ', end='')
    print('  * ')
```

All this outputs is the lines that make up the 'sticks' but I can't figure out how to label the sticks 1-20.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
sticks = 20
width = 1
for x in range(1,10):
    for y in range(1,sticks+1):
        print('%4s'%('*'), end='')
    print("")
for x in range(sticks):
    print("%4d"%(x+1), end='')
```

- There are some formating issues with your code. use `%` format or `format` to properly indent those lines in output.
- Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `str.format` method:

```
for i in range(1, sticks+1):
   print(' {:^4}'.format(i), end='')
```

**Result**:

```
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *  
  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
```

**Explanation**: The `^` symbol center-aligns the field `i` in a space of `width` 4. See the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec) for more detailed explanations of the available specifiers.